# How to setup Papercut SMTP Server for Local Development in .NetCore project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

In Asp.Net how I follow this is, run the downloaded file and Papercut will be installed. Now, just go into your project's Web.config in Visual Studio and add the following into the `<system.net>` tag.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yourfromaddress@email.com">
    <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

How can I config this with .NetCore project?